# What is this Expectation equivalent to?

Tags: probability, integration, stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion

this might sound like a stupid question but I'm trying to figure out how to write this Expectation in integral form:

$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{F( a + \sigma W_{T} + \sigma^{2}/2T)}\right) = \int\quad??$

where $F$ is just some function, and $a$, $T$ and $\sigma$ are arbitrary variables, and $W_{T}$ is a Brownian Motion random variable.

I honestly have no clue how to write it as an integral, I'm doing stats research so this stuff is a bit beyond what I've had to do, but I was told by another researcher that I had to use the heat kernel in the integral, however, as he is not currently at the uni he couldn't elaborate any further. I'd appreciate it if someone here could help me with this, thanks in advance

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{F( a + \sigma W_{T} + \sigma^{2}/2T)}\right) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{F( a + \sigma x + \sigma^{2}/2T)}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi T}}e^{-x^2/2T}dx$$

Comment: Thanks for that! Just one question though - why does the $W_{T}$ term turn into $x$? It makes sense to me since I didn't think it should be sde or anything, but I'm not sure why it's allowed...

Comment: $x$ is just a dummy variable used in the integral, it can be any notation you like as long as it does not cause confusion in the context. The crucial thing is that you need to know the distribution of a Brownian motion at a particular future time point has a normal distribution, and applying this fact https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that the $W_{T}$ term could change the integration result so I just got a bit confused with swapping it to $x$. Thanks!

Comment: If $T$ is a constant, then $W_T$ is a random variable with $\mathcal N(0,T)$ distribution.